# Asynchronous Recursive AWS Lambda call does not work

Tags: java, aws-lambda

I'm trying to call an AWS Lambda function within itself (i.e. recursively). But, unless I block the thread and wait for the response using `future.get()`, the 2nd invocation does not happen.

I have shown my code for the 2 approaches below. I have implemented the Lambda functions using Java (SDK Version 2).

Am I missing something? Can someone explain the reason for this difference we see here? Thanks.

## Non-blocking Approach - HandlerNonBlocking Lambda function (non-blocking)

```
public class HandlerNonBlocking {
    public void process(Map<String, Object> event, Context context) {
        context.getLogger().log("HandlerNonBlocking.process() invoked\n");

        Object isSecond = event.get("isSecond");
        if (isSecond == null) {
            context.getLogger().log("First\n");
        } else {
            context.getLogger().log("Second\n");
            return;
        }

        String json = "{\"isSecond\": \"Y\"}";
        SdkBytes payload = SdkBytes.fromUtf8String(json) ;
        InvokeRequest request = InvokeRequest.builder()
                .functionName("recurring-function")
                .invocationType(InvocationType.EVENT)
                .payload(payload)
                .build();

        try (LambdaAsyncClient lambdaClient = LambdaAsyncClient.create()) {
            context.getLogger().log("Calling again\n");
            CompletableFuture<InvokeResponse> future = lambdaClient.invoke(request);
            // Set a callback
            future.thenAccept(response -> context.getLogger().log("Response status code: " + response.statusCode() + "\n"));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            context.getLogger().log("Error when invoking Lambda function. " +
                    ex.getClass().getSimpleName() + ": " + ex.getMessage() + "\n");
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(5_000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            context.getLogger().log("Sleep interrupted. " + ex.getMessage() + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

**Log - First invocation**

```
START RequestId: c44b0384-c159-4954-a241-8d14044f85db Version: $LATEST
HandlerNonBlocking.process() invoked
First
Calling again
END RequestId: c44b0384-c159-4954-a241-8d14044f85db
```

**There is no second invocation in CloudWatch logs.**

## Blocking Approach - HandlerBlocking Lambda function (block and wait for response)

```
public class HandlerBlocking {
    public void process(Map<String, Object> event, Context context) {
        context.getLogger().log("HandlerBlocking.process() invoked\n");

        Object isSecond = event.get("isSecond");
        if (isSecond == null) {
            context.getLogger().log("First\n");
        } else {
            context.getLogger().log("Second\n");
            return;
        }

        String json = "{\"isSecond\": \"Y\"}";
        SdkBytes payload = SdkBytes.fromUtf8String(json) ;
        InvokeRequest request = InvokeRequest.builder()
                .functionName("recurring-function")
                .invocationType(InvocationType.EVENT)
                .payload(payload)
                .build();

        try (LambdaAsyncClient lambdaClient = LambdaAsyncClient.create()) {
            context.getLogger().log("Calling again\n");
            CompletableFuture<InvokeResponse> future = lambdaClient.invoke(request);
            // Wait for response
            InvokeResponse response = future.get();
            context.getLogger().log("Response status code: " + response.statusCode() + "\n");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            context.getLogger().log("Error when invoking Lambda function. " +
                    ex.getClass().getSimpleName() + ": " + ex.getMessage() + "\n");
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(5_000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            context.getLogger().log("Sleep interrupted. " + ex.getMessage() + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

**Log - First invocation**

```
START RequestId: 1a70cb3e-6752-4427-a703-69ff6f6c404b Version: $LATEST
HandlerBlocking.process() invoked
First
Calling again
Response status code: 202
END RequestId: 1a70cb3e-6752-4427-a703-69ff6f6c404b
```

**Log - Second invocation**

```
START RequestId: db71eb54-547a-4ee9-9e9d-0d5b689588f8 Version: $LATEST
HandlerBlocking.process() invoked
Second
END RequestId: db71eb54-547a-4ee9-9e9d-0d5b689588f8
```

I have tried the 2 approaches shown above.